# index defragmentatio script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Please, need help with running a script for index maintenance.

I am using this tutorial https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

I downloaded the script, run it on my database and then I executed one of the examples with my database name.

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 
'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

It runs through and I would expect it to change database index fragmentation but it does not seem to change anything. I am not sure if I am not missing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have any indexes? Are you sure they are fragmented? How big are your indexes (in terms of pages)?

Comment: yes, I run it on my demo database. Firstly I run my script to find out index fragmentation, there are plenty of them with fragmentation > 50%. For example one is 680KB large with fragm. around 87%

Comment: >>>680KB<<< 85 pages  only. This index is out of consideration, its size is <1MB

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that screams out is that if your indexes are less than 1000 pages, then the script will ignore the indexes. This is because Microsoft's (actually Paul Randall's) recommendations are not to reorder/rebuild indexes with less than 1000 pages. This is because the benefit achieved from the maintenance is "often" negligible due the size of the index.

Secondly, if your index(s) are less than 8 pages then the pages will be stored in a mixed extent. This will also blow your fragmentation readings out of the water.

One thing to note is that external fragmentation (Total Fragmentation), which is what I presume you are talking about, is only really an issue when reading from disk. If you are able to fit all your data in to memory, then you need not worry so much about fragmentation, more statistics maintenance and consistence checking. I mention consistency checking because often people run index maintenance more than CHECKDB.

If you really want to understand index maintenance and performance, try [this](https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/why-defragmenting-your-indexes-isnt-helping/) GroupBy session from Brent Ozar.